# Plot binary variable with value 1 across time

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, heatmap

I have a dataset that includes a binary variable (0 vs 1) across time. I want to plot the occurrence of 1 across time. The idea is to see during which period the 1 occurs more often. Here is an example dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
    
dd <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,100), rep(2,80), rep(3,90)),
                     time = c(seq(from=1,to=100), seq(from=1,to=80), seq(from=1,to=90)),
                     outcome = c(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                                 sample(c(0, 1), 80, replace = TRUE),  
                                 sample(c(0, 1), 90, replace = TRUE)))
```

I am thinking maybe a [heatmap](https://r-graph-gallery.com/283-the-hourly-heatmap.html) like this will give the best presentation
[image]

My heatmap will have my `time` variable instead of `Day` for the x axis and the heat scale will reflect the frequency of 1. For my example dataset, because 1 occurs most often in the second period of time it will be highlighted as the most heated place in the plot.

Comment: Is your data indeed two  years worth of data?

Comment: @JuanC No but I just want to borrow the idea. My real dataset has a longer time scale

Comment: Plot might get a little overwhelming on longer time scales. Why not use weekly moving averages and a lineplot?

Comment: @cliu are the times in your original data frame actual date-times, or just integers in the example? Would you want a series for each ID, or would each time point be colored according to the proportion of IDs that are 1? Your example data doesn't really lend itself to a useful example. Perhaps make a reproducible one similar to your real data set using `rbinom` or even `sample(c(0, 1), 1000, replace = TRUE)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron My real dataset uses integers but they are in milliseconds and so plotting those may look very squeezed. I don't need to group by ID but just pick the longest run of time as the x axis. I tweaked my example dataset and hopefully it is more reproducible now.

Comment: @JuanC I want to plot the frequency of the 1s and so I just can't imagine if lines in a lineplot can reflect the frequency or density of 1s across different periods of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
dd %>% group_by(time) %>% summarise(n_outcome = sum(outcome))   %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = n_outcome)) +  geom_line()
```

[image]

You could obviously tweak it to make it prettier

Comment: Ideally I would still like a heatmap or [density plot](https://r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-chart.html) but if no other answers show up I will accept your answer

Comment: Both are 3-dimensional plots and with the current example we have only two dimensions, so we would need something else to work with (a second time dimension, maybe)

Comment: To add to my comment, in the case of your example the dimensions are hour, day and temperature, you'd need something similar to replicate that example

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand what you're looking for. Is it something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
dd %>%
  group_by(time) %>% 
  summarise(outcome=sum(outcome)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=time, fill=outcome)) + geom_tile(aes(y=1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7) + scale_fill_viridis_c(option='plasma')
```

[image]

It does highlight the second period as the highest frequency of 1 as required. If you need to split it into months (as per your example image) then use `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` with the relevant month variable.

**Edit:**

To get a heat map more like the example in the question, you need another dimention. I have split your time dimension into 2 dimensions in the example below:

```
dd <- dd %>%
        mutate(
               period1=as.integer(time / 10) * 10 ,
               period2=time %% 10
        )

dd %>%
  group_by(period1, period2) %>% 
  summarise(outcome=sum(outcome)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=period1, y=period2, fill=outcome)) + geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option='plasma') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,10)) +   scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:10)
```

Which gives the output below:

[image]

Comment: This is close but can we use dots instead of bars? I am thinking maybe can use `jitter` to add a small value to each 1 so that in the end it shows the density of 1 in each time period. Maybe it should look more like a [density plot](https://r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-chart.html)

Comment: @cliu, I am not sure how to do this unless you have another dimension for the y-axis. I have edited my answer to split the time into 2 dimensions as an example.